# Set executable file permission using maven assembly

Tags: java, maven, debian, ubuntu-16.04, maven-assembly-plugin

How can I say give executable permision to shell script reside under {project.basedir}/src/deb/init. I dont want to package them to different folder or anything but I just want to give the executable permission to that file. I have add below but when I extract the debian and check the file permission its still looks as below,

-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser  ms-media.sh

Does this assembly file is correct? What am I missing here?

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id/> 
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <useDefaultExcludes/>
      <includes><include>*.sh</include></includes>
      <excludes/>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
      <directoryMode/>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/deb/init</directory>
      <lineEnding/>
      <filtered/>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And I have this in my pom.xml. default.xml is also in the same level as of pom.xml

```
             <plugin>
                <!-- Assembly Plugin for the win! -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>default.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: First I would recommend to upgrade your maven-assembly-plugin to the most recent version see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: @khmarbaise I have upgrade it to 3.1.0 but then I get below error. I remove the version tag also and tried with 2.5.1
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.1:single (assembly) on project: No formats specified in the execution parameters or the assembly descriptor.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FALCON-1898  Also earlier I ran only mvn clean package command. Should I have to execute a different maven command?

Comment: what is the format i should put in my case?

Comment: As the error message indicates you have to define formats either zip, tar, tar.gz etc. and of course you should define an `<id>..</id>`...

Answer (score 2):

Just for future readers: I was also searching for a solution and came across this question. Years later the update problem did not apply to me. The above example was already sufficient.

All I had to add to my assembly file was

```
<fileMode>0755</fileMode>
```